# Should long paragraphs be aligned justified or just left aligned?

Tags: gui-design, human-interface-guideline

For better readability which would be better for long paragraphs: align-justified or aligned-left?

*Reason for asking:* Aligned justify gives a better visual appeal but many tutorial and learning sites do not align-justify. Why?

Comment: There are a lot of variables that can have an effect on an answer. Purpose: the purpose of the text (instructions, a wedding invite, an article?), culture (I’m assuming it’s not in Arabic and the design. A little more context to this question will go a long way.

Answer (score 5):

Align-left is better for readability, because it have consistent spaces between words. 
It was find out that readers read faster and comprehend more informations when text is evenly spaced. Justify text is pretty, it can fit more characters in the line, but it is specced randomly. Human brain have to work harder to follow it.

More about: http://www.zaetric.com/pdf/White%20Paper%20-%20Readability%20Legibility%20and%20Text%20Justification.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Left align text is most favourable and used in web and mobile user interfaces because the human eye tends in "F-Patterns" - (read from left to right). 
but if your visual interface/design is for publication/print then align-justified will also works

Read this article:
https://99designs.com/blog/tips/6-principles-of-visual-hierarchy/